# Check if OrderBy string is valid

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dynamic

```
var query = db.Customers
          .Where("City == @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10)
          .OrderBy(someStringVariable)
          .Select("new(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

How can I check if someStringVariable is a valid order by expression before I run this query? 
I want to check it instead of catching ParseException.

- Valid string: "City ASC, Phone DESC"
- Invalid string is not existing field or mistype in DESC: "City1 DESC1"

With help of Anu I am using this function but I would prefer some "TryParseQuery" in the Linq.Dynamic namespace.

```
    public static bool IsValidOrderString(Type type, string ordering)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ordering)) return false;

        var orderList = ordering.Trim().Split(',');
        var fields = type.GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name).ToArray();
        foreach (var orderItem in orderList)
        {
            var order = orderItem.TrimEnd();
            if (order.EndsWith(" ASC", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || order.EndsWith(" DESC", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) order = order.Substring(0, order.Length - 4);
            if (!fields.Contains(order.Trim())) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: The short answer is you can't do it 100% reliably.

Comment: Can you share some examples of valid and invalid values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @mjwills pointed out, it is hard to do it with 100% reliability, but one thing you could do is compare 'someStringVariable' with list of columns in your table. You can find the list of columns via

```
.GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name).ToArray();
```

Again you need to be aware that this has many pitfalls. Properties can be mapped to column names that are not same as the property name.